# How to automate Java applet?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, applet, automated-tests

I have to create a test script and I am using Selenium, but I am not able to record or edit the rich text editor Ephox. So is there a way to do it with Selenium as I came across an article stating Java applets cannot be recorded using Selenium. Also if not Selenium any other tools that can be used for this purpose?

Here's the link for the Ephox for your reference :  http://editlive.com/demo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[LiveConnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect) can help you with that!

There is even a tool for it and Selenium (though I'm not using it, so I can't tell whether it works well or not): https://web.archive.org/web/20150526204052/http://fest.codehaus.org/Selenium

Other than that, [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) could possibly be useful, too.

Comment: How to use LiveConnect?

Comment: Can you demonstrate how these are used with an example?

Answer (score 5):

You can't reliably automate an applet using a web testing tool.  You need to use a Swing testing tool.  There are a few out there, but two I'd recommend are:

http://code.google.com/p/fest/

and

http://www.uispec4j.org/

The second one is also interesting because it allows you to write unit tests for the UI that don't require it being rendered on the screen.

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how these tools would be used?

Comment: Am hearing FEST is deprecated and not advised to use. Please clarify and share any examples.