# Why I can't use selenium to test on mmorpg games?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I am a starter in software testing. Just watched a video on youtube. I recorded few steps for gmail in selenium IDE and replayed it. all worked fine. Then I tried on runescape and suddenly selenium can't record a single step. I can't understand. It's web based and selenium should be able to record the steps and replay it. 
Can anybody explain me what is the difference between these two things I tried. 
Why selenium is not working on the game application? 
Can I assume that these automation tools wont work on these these type of MMORPG sites? 
or Is there any specific type of tool which works on these type of games?

Comment: You are totally misunderstanding it. Runescape uses Java, Selenium does not work with Java. If you are trying to create a bot for Runescape, Selenium is **NOT** the way to do it.

Comment: Than what is the ideal tool for that?

Comment: I read in few places that the selenium can generate java codes. I may have misinterpreted it though.

Comment: Yes you have. It generates Java/C# code so that the test developer can use it with a language of their choice, it does not mean that it can access Java applets. Runescape is a game running in a Java applet. iMacros is one product that can interact with Java applets.

Comment: Thanks Arran. So I should go for iMacros instead? or there are other options also to try?

Comment: how to automate java applet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765682

Answer (score 2):

While the discussion under the answer is correct, there is one more thing you should consider - its **legal issues**: As long as I know, most of MMORPG games actively refuse bots and/or scripting, because they care more about that live player plays against live player and not bot.

So before you continue with automated testing of MMORPG, you should do:

- Check terms and conditions of that particular game if automation of players movement (actions ...) is allowed and if yes, to what level is it allowed)
- Probably also check with site owner/admin/moderator and explain, what do you need to test and (maybe) arrange special account allowing such testing

Comment: +1, I did not consider the legal implications.