# Automate Java web applet testing using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, applet

I am trying to automate my web application using Selenium. I am able to log in by using Selenium, but after that one web applet is generated where I can't get the handle of that application.

Is it really possible to get the automation?

Comment: Related: [How to automate Java applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10765682/3357935)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, the Selenium WebDriver itself is, as you've found out, not going to get you any where with Java Applets.

For the Java language though, the `Robot` class might help.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: i am trying to use FEST-SWING with Selenium-RC to automate my application. But it is not worked out for me. The issues i faced are   1) It will work on only Swing based applications, not for AWT components. 2) I don't have any control over the application code i need to test. So based on my analysis i come to conclusion that we are not able to automate applet from selenium. Correct me when i am wrong. @Arran Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know its too late :). I assume when you say "one web applet is generated", it means a new pop-up is generated. (correct me if I'm wrong)

I use to switch between window handles like this,

//Save your current(i.e old) handle
   //Find new window & Get the new handle and switch window

```
 string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
 PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
 string newHandle = finder.Click(driver.FindElement(By.Id("primarycontactid")));
  driver.SwitchTo().Window(newHandle);
```